# tooltip formatter Highcharts not work with Firefox ? - Bug?

Tags: debugging, firefox, highcharts

I'm using **3D Scatter Chart" of `Highcharts` with version **4.1.4**
I noticed that **tooltip formatter** doesn't work on firefox developement edition **64.0b3**.

This is really strange because i'm sure that my code is not change and in latest days worked.

```
                formatter: function() { 
                    if((this.point.x < this.point.series.xAxis.max+0.1) && (this.point.options.stato == true)) {    //se il marker è visibile (cioè nel grafico) e nei confini del grafico mostro il fumetto                    
                        return '<div style="white-space:pre"><b class="colorunder"><span style="color:#0071B3;font-weight:bolder">Magnitude</b>:  </span>'+this.point.magn+' M<br/><b class="colorunder"><span style="color:#0071B3;font-weight:bolder">Date time</b>:  </span>'+this.point.data+'<br /><b class="colorunder"><span style="color:#0071B3;font-weight:bolder">Longitude</b>:  </span>'+this.point.x+'\u00B0'+'   '+' <b class="colorunder"><span style="color:#0071B3;font-weight:bolder">Latitude</b>:  </span>'+this.point.z+'\u00B0 <br/><b class="colorunder"><span style="color:#0071B3;font-weight:bolder">Depth</b>:  </span>'+this.point.y+' Km</div>';
                    } 
                    return false;
                }
```

Tooltip formatter on mouse over event (or touch) works very well with other browsers or firefox mobile.

Is a bug ?

Comment: the [4.1.4 version](https://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog#highcharts-v4.1.4) is 3 years old, can you update the highcharts version to a 6.x version ?

Comment: I’m fear that some code will can’t work yet

Comment: Try to reproduce your problem, then you can report it as a new issue on Highcharts Github: github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53836603/highcharts-highstocks-tooltip-does-not-work-on-latest-firefox-64-0-with-usehtm). Try disabling animation.

Answer (score 1):

disabling clip and enabling stickyTracking seems to be a workaround for firefox tooltip events.

`plotOptions: {
    series: {
        // stickyTracking: false
        clip: false
    }
}`