# Highcharts (highstocks) tooltip does not work on latest firefox 64.0 with useHTML=true

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, highcharts

I'm using highstocks in an Angular web application to display a chart with multiple series. 
After updating to the latest firefox version (64.0) the HTML tooltip stopped displaying.
It still works well in google chrome, but for some reason firefox does not display the tooltip.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I checked the html tooltip on latest Firefox - version 64.0, macOS version 10.14.1 and it works fine. I prepared a simple example of Highstock in the Angular sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/729mw217j1, could you check it on your machine? Feel free to edit this example to reproduce your issue and when you manage please send me it, thanks.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel thanks for the reply. I've tried on the same version of Firefox but my MacOS version is 10.13 and the code sandbox does not load. Same goes for most Highcharts demos on JSFiddle. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @mila I've no idea why it's happening. It's only the issue on your machine with Firefox browser?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel thanks, I can see it working. Seems Firefox does not load it on some machines. I see the tooltip works in your example with useHTML, it may be a specific issue with my highcharts config. I'll keep investigating, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

setting stickyTracking: true for firefox fixed it for me.
could not solve this with stickyTracking: false

what I saw though is that FF renders the chart differently.

Comment: is there any way to make this work with stickyTracking: false?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a known issue with this version of Firefox. See [Higchart Issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9745).

In my case I could solve it by disabling animation:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        animation: false;
        ...
    },
    ...
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false;
        }
    }
}
```

Try it!